When exactly do we use simplicity?
Here it is said that other things being equal, simpler explanations are better.
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/simplicity/
"Most philosophers beleve that, other things be echual, simpler theories are better."
Here they say that there are two versions of Occam's razor:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor
"other things being equal, simpler explanations are generally better than more complex ones"
AND
"simpler hypotheses are generally better than the complex ones"
So when should we use simplicity:

other things being equal?

Or

in any situation?

When can Occam's Razor be used?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


“It can scarcely be denied that the supreme goal of all theory is to
make the irreducible basic elements as simple and as few as possible
without having to surrender the adequate representation of a single
datum of experience.”
-Albert Einstein, in a lecture in 1933

Often paraphrased as an aphorism:

“Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler”


When should we use simplicity:

other things being equal?

Or

in any situation? Wikipedia says that there are two versions of Occam's razor.


If both theories predict the same thing you choose the theory with the least number of postulates the least number of degrees of freedom. If both are the same then it doesn't matter which one you choose.

What does the version of Occam's razor mean that says: "simpler hypotheses are generally better than the complex ones" en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor If we can apply simplicity whenever we want then will solipsism be true by default?
